# Using class and frames with tkinter getting app "Not Responding" msg in Titlebar. Need Multithreading/Processing assistance to resolve

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I am new to python/tkinter, running python 3.8. I have run into an issue where I need to start a thread/process that will update pb1(progressbar) slowly while CSF.addOrders is active.  CSF.addOrders runs on a server and takes between 10 sec and 5 min depending on # of orders. It causes the app to show "Not Responding" even though it is working. Also, the time delay makes it so the app users don't know that the program is still running as progressbar(pb1) doesn't update.

I have simplified the code I am using to show the critical segments. I need pb1(progressbar) to slowly update while CSF.addOrders is running and for it to terminate as soon as CSF.addOrders is completed. I have read a bunch of the posts on Not Responding but have been unable to figure out what to do. Beacause of the use of frames and classes it does not seem to have an answer already provided. Any help/guidance would be very much appreciated.

**This is the Code that Fixes tkinter GUI "Not Responding" and allows the progressbar to continue until the Server side function is completed.**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk  as ttk
import ClientServer_Functions as CSF
import threading
import queue
import logging
import time

# Log File
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# create the handlers and call logger.addHandler(logging_handler)
if not logger.handlers:
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('GUI_Logger.log')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.propagate = False

class sample(tk.Tk):   
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.shared_data = {
            "fName": tk.StringVar(),  # userInfo[0][0] 
            "username": tk.StringVar(),  # userInfo[0][1]
            "password": tk.StringVar(),  # userInfo[0][2]
            "custSym": tk.StringVar(),  # userInfo[0][3]
            "email": tk.StringVar(),  # userInfo[0][4]
            "sPath": tk.StringVar(),  # userInfo[0][5]
            "FTP_User": tk.StringVar(),  # userInfo[0][6]
            "FTP_Password": tk.StringVar(),   # userInfo[0][7]
            "fType": tk.StringVar()
            }
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        global bgColor
        bgColor = "black"
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Trade, blank): #there are other frames I create that are not listed
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.config(bg=bgColor)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(Trade)

    def get_page(self, page_class):
        return self.frames[page_class]
    
    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()
        
class Trade(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller
        
        tk.Label(self, bg=bgColor).pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="TRADES", bg=bgColor, fg="yellow").pack(pady=20)
        tk.Button(self, text="Orders", command=lambda: [self.setFType("Orders"), self.files()]).pack(pady=10)
        self.statusbar = tk.Label(self)
        self.statusbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
    
    def setFType(self, fType):
        self.controller.shared_data["fType"].set(fType)    
    
   
    def aOrders(self, ls):
        l = ls[0]
        print("starting t1")
        time.sleep(1)
        result, msg, FTP_outFile = CSF.addOrders(l,"u", "p", "fp", "sp", "c") 
        return result, msg, FTP_outFile
        
   
    def files(self): 
        fType = self.controller.shared_data["fType"].get()
        self.statusbar['text'] = "Running..."
        pb1 = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=250, mode='determinate')
        pb1['value'] += 10
        pb1.place(relx=.25, rely=.88)
        
        que = queue.Queue()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = lambda q, arg : q.put(self.aOrders(arg)), args = (que, [logger, 2]))
        t1.start()
        for x in range(100):
            if t1.is_alive():
                print("update pb1")
                pb1['value'] += 2
                tk.Tk.update(self)
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print(que.get())
                break
        print("do balance of program...")

class blank(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller=controller 
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = sample()
    app.geometry("500x500+500+150")
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: frames and classes are unrelated to this problem. Tkinter is single-threaded, so as long as `CSF.addOrders` doesn't return, the UI will be frozen. It needs to run in a thread or separate process.

Comment: I have updated my pitiful attempt using threads...which I don't fully understand well. But it still waits for the 1st thread to finish before beginning the second.

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=self.aOrders("u", "p", "fp", "sp", "c"))` _immediately runs `self.aOrders("u", "p", "fp", "sp", "c")` before passing it as the `target` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will block here:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.aOrders(u, p, fp, sp, c))
```

This just executes the function and waits for it to exit. Try

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.aOrders, args=(u, p, fp, sp, c))
```

instead. Not sure if it is the only problem your program has but this is the obvious one.

Comment: Hope this helps. What I am trying to do is run the above code (runs on a server and takes time before finished) and until it returns increase the progressbar slowly so user knows to wait and tkinter doesn't show "Not Responding"

Comment: Hannu - Using your "obvious" Fix, I was able to work out the rest of my issues and provided for anyone else with a tkinter GUI reporting "Not Responding" who needs the final code. Thank you...it was well worth the 50 points!

Comment: @Hedgebox: If this answer was what you wanted, you should accept it and manually award the bounty (by clicking on the "+50" button next to the answer), so that it's guaranteed to go to Hannu, and so that other users know that the bounty has already been awarded. Right now, the bounty doesn't appear to have been awarded yet.

Comment: Sorry, it told me I had to wait 24hrs and then I was away.  Thank you so much for the help Hannu!